# Which should be used - ConcurrentHashMap putIfAbsent or locking the map

Tags: java, multithreading, spring, concurrency, synchronization

I have a situation where callers would like to get object of a bean depending upon current instance(identifier). Now if object of the bean exists for current instance, then it should not be created again. So there are two ways(I think) this can be done -

```
1. Using putIfAbsent of ConcurrentHashMap

beanObject = objectFactory.get(); // this will create new instance every time
// even if not required
beanObject = beanMapForInstance.putIfAbsent(name, beanObject);
return beanObject;
```

Or

```
2. By Locking the map

beanObject = beanMapForInstance.get(name); // beanMapForInstance is a ConcurrentHashMap
if(beanObject == null){
    synchronized (beanMapForInstance) {
        beanObject = beanMapForInstance.get(name);
        if(beanObject == null){
            beanObject = objectFactory.getObject();
            beanMapForInstance.put(name, beanObject);
        }
    }
}
return beanObject;
```

In first method new object is created every time so I think second should be preferred. But findbugs shows issue for second option that synchronization performed on ConcurrentHashMap, so which one should be used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, there is no choice: You cannot lock a `ConcurrentHashMap`.  More precisely, locking a `ConcurrentHashMap` does not work as you expected.  It does not make your action thread-safe, as thread-safety operations in `ConcurrentHashMap` is not achieved by synchronizing the object itself.

Quoted from [Javadoc of ConcurrentHashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html):

> This class is fully interoperable with Hashtable in programs that rely on its thread safety but not on its synchronization details

If you do not want to unnecessary create a value, then you can use `computeIfAbsent` if you are using JDK 8+, which you can delay the instantiation until it is really needed.

Comment: Well, the lock won't affect any other code, but above pattern2 will still work as long as no one else has access to the map (which is presumably private to this bean manager class). The lock object could just as well be a completely unrelated lock object (does not have to be the map itself). In fact, that's probably preferred for clarity.

Comment: `computeIfAbsent` is nice.

Comment: If no one else is using the ConcurrentHashMap, why bother using it? Simply use a blocking HashMap is going to give same, if not better, performance as synchronizing a ConcurrentHashMap.

Comment: by "no one else using the map" I mean, no other piece of code except the fragment shown above. Of course, that fragment could be called by multiple threads concurrently.

Comment: That's what I mean, if only this fragment of code is using the ConcurrentHashMap, changing it to a synchronized HashMap is actually better than synchronizing the ConcurrentHashMap

Comment: Why would a "blocking HashMap" perform better? Then you also have to synchronize the `get`s (which are presumable *a lot* more frequent). With CHM, you can `get` outside of the synchronized block.

Comment: 'You cannot lock a ConcurrentHashMap', locking works on ConcurrentHashMap as well. I think Javadoc suggests to use internal methods as you and @Thilo pointed, computeIfAbsent and putIfAbsent instead of custom synchronization.

Comment: @Thilo You have your point here :)  Map update is going to be worse but read is still going to be better.

Comment: @SachinGorade you can lock but if other thread is updating the map without synchronizing it (as ConcurrentHashMap is supposed to be used in lock-free manner and is supposed to be thread-safe), it will give you unexpected result

Comment: "locking works on ConcurrentHashMap as well." No, it doesn't. You cannot "lock" the CHM in the way you can a normal HashMap, in that your lock would prevent another (independent) `get` or `put` from proceeding. The CHM does not synchronize its own methods on itself.

Answer (score 0):

How about checking for existence first and only then putIfAbsent ?

```
beanObject = beanMapForInstance.get(name);
if (beanObject == null){
    beanObject = beanMapForInstance.putIfAbsent(
      name, objectFactory.get());
}
```

Will work 99.99% of the time, and in the very rare race condition case, you call a redundant constructor (which apparently is not a problem for you except for performance considerations).

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Correct me if I am wrong, your code is doing the same as second solution posted by me but is doing it internally?

Comment: Well, it avoids the synchronized block. Presumably ConcurrentHashMap is either completely lock-free or does it more efficiently at least.

Comment: @SachinGorade I think you missed the point: this approach cannot avoid all cases of creating value unnecessarily. However it is good enough in real world situation, unless you need to absolutely avoid redundant bean creation.

Comment: If you do need to avoid all cases (and have Java 8), use `computeIfAbsent`